# Powershell script to check IP connection and delete IP address lease

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a Powershell script to check IP connection and delete IP address lease if the connection is False. Here is what I have so far.

```
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName 10.5.5.100 -Count 1 -Quiet) -eq False {netsh dhcp server \\computername scope 10.15.1.0 delete lease 10.15.1.100}

if (Test-Connection -ComputerName 10.5.5.100 -Count 1 -Quiet -eq False) {netsh dhcp server \\computername scope 10.15.1.0 delete lease 10.15.1.100}
```

I am thinking my syntax is wrong here but can't quite figure it out. This is on a 2008 server.

Bonus: Obviously I am using this to check a scope and any addresses that are not in use I want to remove them. I could just change the lease time to less but that is not policy so I have to come up with another way. So if there is a way to go from 10.5.5.100 through 10.5.5.254 removing any IPs that are not active that would be great.

Comment: The If should be more like `if ((Test-Connection -ComputerName 10.5.5.100 -Count 1 -Quiet) -eq $False)`. Evaluate `Test-Connection` separately then compare it to `$False`

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName 10.5.5.100 -Count 1 -Quiet) {}
else {netsh dhcp server \\computername scope 10.15.1.0 delete lease 10.15.1.100}
```

Or if you want to save the result of test:

```
$live = Test-Connection -ComputerName 10.5.5.100 -Count 1 -Quiet
if (!$live)
    { netsh dhcp server \\computername scope 10.15.1.0 delete lease 10.15.1.100 }
```

Comment: Actually @Matt gave the answer already: you only missed `$False` with `False` and one more surrounding brackets after `$False`